# I need to compare property values in StringTemplate

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I have a list of tuples that I need to emit a C-like boolean expression from:

```
ranges = [('a','z'),('0','9'),('_','_')]
```

my template:

```
"$ranges:{'$it.0$'<=c&&c<='$it.1$'}; separator='||'$"
```

this outputs:

```
'a'<=c&&c<='z'||'0'<=c&&c<='9'||'_'<=c&&c<='_'
```

I would like to check if `$it.0$` is the same as `$it.1$` and output `c==='$it.0$'` in this case (in my example this would generate `c==='_'` for the last tuple). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have any computation in the template (see [Stringtemplate compare strings does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195828/stringtemplate-compare-strings-does-not-work)).

A possible way of getting around this would be to use a custom Range class, and store the functionality inside that. Then you could call a method on the range object that returned whether or not the `from` and `to` values are equal.

```
$ranges:{ range | $if(range.fromToEqual)$c === '$range.from$'$else$'$range.from$' <= c && c <= '$range.to$'$endif$}; separator=" || "$
```

where the method in the Range class is as follows:

```java
public boolean getFromToEqual() { // note the 'get' prefix
    return from == to;
}
```

output:

```
'a' <= c && c <= 'b'||'1' <= c && c <= '9'|| c === '_'
```